# populating dropdown list with column names in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a database in SQL Server with a table that has 18 columns. I want to create a drop down list in visual studio 2008 that will display each of these column names and be data bound. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'YourTableName'
order by ordinal_position
```

This will pull the data that you're looking for and all that's left is binding it to your drop down list.

Comment: Does the user require higher privileges to query the `information_schema` system table compared to normal user tables?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at either of:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

...anything like what you're after?